# Can a tree data structure be empty?

Tags: tree, binary

I am a CS student, and my Data Structure Professor told us a tree cannot be empty, thus a binary tree is NOT a tree (because binary tree CAN be empty).
After looking up for this online, I have found couple of sources claiming a binary tree IS a tree, and that a tree CAN be empty.
I just want to make sure I get this right:

1. Is A binary tree a tree?
2. Can A tree be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this link](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Tree) says:

*A tree data structure can be defined recursively (locally) as a collection of nodes (starting at a root node), where each node is a data structure consisting of a value, together with a list of references to nodes (the "children"), with the constraints that no reference is duplicated, and none points to the root.*

So I think a binary tree (as we can understand from it's name) **is a tree**. (that every node can have at most two children)

and again base on this definition a tree can **not** be empty.

I hope it helps.

Comment: In section 2.3 - Trees - of Volume 1 of The Art of Computer Programming, Knuth goes out of his way to state that binary trees are NOT actually trees, and that one of the defining characteristics of binary trees is that they can be empty, while trees cannot.

Given this, I would say there is not 100% agreement that the accepted answer (that a binary tree is a tree and that a binary tree cannot be empty) is correct.